# Formik radio values not freshest from within a callback

Tags: reactjs, formik

I use formik to build a form with two radio buttons:

```
const RadioButton = ({
  field: { name, value, onChange, onBlur },
  id,
  label,
  className,
  onSelect,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name={name}
        id={id}
        type="radio"
        value={id}
        checked={id === value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onClick={onSelect}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        {...props}
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        radioGroup: ""
      }}
      render={({ values }) => (
        <form>
          <Field
            component={RadioButton}
            name="radioGroup"
            id="radioOption1"
            onSelect={() => console.log(values)}
            label="Option 1"
          />
          <Field
            component={RadioButton}
            name="radioGroup"
            id="radioOption2"
            onSelect={() => console.log(values)}
            label="Option 2"
          />
          <p>{JSON.stringify(values)}</p>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

My goal is to get notified when a radio element was selected. So I pass a onSelect callback to the RadioButton component and add it to the onClick handler of the input field: `onClick={onSelect}`.

The notification works. However in

```
onSelect={() => console.log(values)}
```

values does not contain the selected radio. Strange enough,

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(values)}</p>
```

shows the selected value as you can see here:

[image]

Try it for yourself:

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-radio-and-checkbox-inputs-vguym

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: You are using `onSelect` which happens as soon as you click on an element (before re-rendering). It shows you the state of `values` at that time which happens to be your `initialValues` object. Once it re-renders i.e. the form because formik prop change due to the event i.e. selection of the state of the radio button `radioGroup` value changed, it forces re-render and thus you see correct values in the output on screen. If you put in console.log outside of it right under your form tag it will show you updated state at the time of re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `onSelect` which happens as soon as you click on an element (before re-rendering). It shows you the state of `values` at that time which happens to be your `initialValues` object. 
Once it re-renders i.e. the form because formik prop change due to the event i.e. selection of the state of the radio button `radioGroup` value changed, it forces re-render and thus you see correct values in the output on screen. If you put in `console.log` outside of it right under your form tag it will show you updated state at the time of re-render

Here's updated snippet to reflect what's happening at and after click event

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-radio-and-checkbox-inputs-mgps7

It also shows info on the usage that I use mostly in my code base for various scenarios.